# PHP's pow() with a negative number as input doesn't work

Tags: php

PHP's `pow()` doesn't want to process the following:

```
 pow(-5,1/3);
```

While in fact it [is supposed to work](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29). How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: What is the result? An incorrect answer or an unexpected error/exception?

Comment: It prolly says NAN, You could use rounding on the second param

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php#example-3364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mathematically* -5<sup>1/3</sup> is defined as simply the cube root of -5, which is around -1.71.

However, there's no way to precisely represent 1/3 in floating point. So, you're asking PHP to calculate something like -5<sup>0.33333333333333331482961</sup>.

Now, if that exponent's exact rational expansion has an even denominator, the result is purely imaginary. If the exact rational expansion has an odd denominator, the result is purely real. The problem is that it is impossible to determine whether the denominator is "even" or "odd" because of the inadequate precision.

So, PHP doesn't bother. It just tells you that you can't do it, and that's the end of the story.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically taking the 3rd root of a negative number here.

This is not always possible in the real number space. So in some cases you would need an imaginary unit to solve that equation.

It seems as if php just outputs `NAN` for cases where the base is negative and the exponent < 1.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez Wolfram Alpha can handle imaginary numbers. ([Your equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-5%29%5E%281%2F3%29))

Comment: N-th roots work if n % 2 != 0. Mathematically, `pow(-5,1/3)` should work.

Comment: (-2)^3 = -8 so (-8)^(1/3) = -2.

Answer (score 1):

As PeeHaa has pointed out, [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php#example-3364) state that for some exponents the results can be "weird".

Algebraically the following is valid:

```
-x^(p) == -1*(x^p)
```

You could use this as a workaround. Speaking in code:

```
$x = pow(5,1/3)*-1;
```

But be wary of exponents like n/m with m being an even number!

You could use the following function to cover that as well:

```
function real_pow($base, $exponent){
  if($base < 0){
    if($exponent >= 1) return pow($base * -1, $exponent) * -1;
    else{
      if(is_nan(pow($base, $exponent))) return false;
      else return pow($base, $exponent);
    }
  }else{
    return pow($base, $exponent);
  }
}
```

This function will return valid pow's if the result is not a complex number. If it is, it will return false.

Comment: The problem is not with negative exponent but base.

Comment: That is true if and only if the exponent is a rational with denominator being an odd number.

Comment: Can you guys write a function which will do this properly?

Comment: This answer does give the correct way to do this. `pow(5,1/3) * -1`

Comment: Note that this will only give the real number root, not the complex number roots.

Comment: True that and thanks for pointing it out! I have come up with a function to handle negative bases where it should work and return false if it doesn't work - please check if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$base=-5;
$exponent=1/3;

$result = ($base<0?-1:1)*pow(abs($base),$exponent);
```

It is not valid for exponents being rationals with even denominator because it produces a complex number which PHP does not handle. You can write your own class/functions or google it, there are some in the web, but I never tested.